# Java distributed database data sharing

Tags: java, database, distributed, sharing

I want applications to share certain database data. I want one application to retrieve and display certain table views of data produced by another application. Do you know of any open source technologies that I can use for such a distributed solution?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem. Why not just connect both apps to the same database? One app could write something that the other app could then read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need an open source RDBMS (of which there are a number; e.g. MySQL, Postgres, Derby, Firebird, etc) and matching JDBC drivers.